# Find a character in a user drawn string at a given point

Tags: c#, drawing

So I'm building a custom control in C# (not WPF), and I basically want to implement text highlighting with the mouse.

How do I efficiently find the character at a given `Point` (say where the mouse is clicked) in a string?  I have the layout rectangle of the string as it was drawn and I could calculate the length of the string up to every character until I find the one closest to where the mouse is clicked... but there has to be a better way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can’t you use a read-only `TextBox` control? That will do the work for you.

Comment: Are you deriving this control from Textbox?

Comment: @Scottie - Nope, it only inherits from UserControl.  RichTextBox and TextBox aren't quite what I need, and I'm really just curious to learn how to build my own good custom controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to do this, I would look at it backward.
I'd keep the text entered as a `string` member in the control, so at all times I know what is actually entered in the control (like the `Text` property in a `TextBox`).
Then I would use the `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sy6awsb.aspx) and I would keep measuring the length of the string repeatedly until I pass the X coordinate of the mouse within the control, right then I know how many characters are chosen.

For example, assume the user has the text `Hello` written in the control.
And the X coordinate hit right between the `l` and the `o`, which could be of value 20.
Then I would repeatedly calling `MeasureText()` on the following strings:

- `H`: width of 5 pixels.
- `He`: width of 10 pixels.
- `Hel`: width of 14 pixels.
- `Hell`: width of 17 pixels.
- `Hello`: width of 22 pixels.

Then I know the mouse was hit between the `l` and the `o`, so I would then highlight the text `Hell`.

Sorry for the distasteful example =)

**UPDATE:**
You can optimize this a bit by calculating the lengths in a binary-search-tree-like fashion.
Just like you would look up a name in the phonebook, you don't look page by page, but rather split in half as you go along, getting closer and closer until it's definitely between these two pages.
Similarly, especially for long string values of the control, calculate the width of the entire string, then half its length, and split there.  I think that would be `O(n log n)` at that point.
Of course it would be `O(1)` if the text is of fixed width =)

Comment: Yeah that is pretty much what I'm doing now.  I may just have to keep this solution if I can't find a more efficient way.

Comment: Oh and the text can wrap multiple lines.

Comment: @climbage; that would be a bit of a challenge.  You first need to translate the Y coordinate into the index of the character that starts that line, then you follow the same logic above.

Comment: I like the binary search idea.  That might just do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can do to build upon BeemerGuy's great suggestion is to precalculate an array of offsets.  As the string is changed (the user types or the property is set in code) you can recalculate the offset array.  That will save you the call to MeasureFont on the mouse clicks and will make finding the character trivial.  You basically iterate the array until you find the nearest character.  Since the offsets are implicitly sorted by value you can even use a binary search to make it more effective.

Comment: I like that; it's more like indexing.  That's a good way to optimize it, especially when we're talking about real-time interactivity; quick responsiveness is mandatory there!

Comment: The only problem with that is that the word wrapping of my text can change at any time so the offsets of each character will change, unless you have some way around that.

Comment: @climbage; actually this would be ideal for your multi-line case; you create the offsets at the beginning of each line, then you simply translate Y into the line number of the array, and combine that with my answer's logic.

Comment: Make a two dimensional array indexed by line and character position.  So you check the line based on font height (which is usually constant for a particular font and font size regardless of glyph).  Then you index that array of offsets to find the character.

Comment: @BeemerGuy - You're absolutely right, I wish I could set both of your answers as correct.

Comment: @climbage; I agree with you. SO should add this feature of choosing supporting answer(s), because it happens a lot to me when I pick people's answers.

Comment: Ok, so it gets trickier I think--text doesn't necessarily wrap per character with `Graphics.DrawString`.  It can wrap a whole word, so the character offsets might not match what's actually on screen.

Comment: @climbage More complex indeed.  Now you are entering the realm of text processing.  Since it's impossible (or very error prone at best) to guess at the algorithm DrawString uses you may have to fall back on your own drawing.  In that case you can abstract or invert the dependency to that algorithm and supply it yourself.  That way the code that prebuilds the arrays can use the same logic that the code that draws the string does - in fact you could pre build the arrays when drawing the string or draw the string from the pre-built arrays even.

Comment: In my previous comment I assume that the DrawString algorithm isn't public, but even if it is you shouldn't depend on it since it can change in the future without notice.  That's why I suggested the IoD approach of supplying the algorithm to a custom draw string method and to the method that pre builds the offset arrays.

Comment: @SRM Looks like that's the way to go--thanks for the help. I hate to reinvent the wheel, but sometimes that's just what you have to do.